# dota 2 start laging after changing ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, games, steam

I remove my ubuntu 16.04 with unity desktop and install a fresh ubuntu 16.04 with gnome desktop, when I was playing dota 2 on my previous ubuntu it worked very well, however in my new ubuntu it I can't play it anymore it has alot's of lag and I don't think this is graphic problem
here is my lspci command result:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

I install mesa-utlis for my intel graphic but that wont help I had still lags in the game I am wondering what is the reason I have this problem? any suggestion would be thankful.
I tried and installed `lxde` desktop and set my dota setting on low network however I still have lots of lag my network connection is good my Google ping is 100ms when I run `intel_gpu_top` command and it showed render busy 37% in the middle of game I am confused what is the problem here

Comment: When you say "lag" do you mean input lag, low framerates, or network lag?

Comment: my network connection is good I think it's a fps drop lag

Answer (score 0):

If you have a compositor activated, disable it when play. The composing system will cause a lot of "lag", while playing, but the reason is the resource consuption of the composer. Also, I recommend you to install a lightweight desktop like **LXDE** to have better performance. However, if still want to use Gnome, try to use a lightweight desktop theme, this could contribute a little. Also, disable VSync.

**In the game:**

- Reduce the render quality in game.
- Disable the Steam overlay.
- Go to Settings, Options, To Advanced options, and select I have a Low-end Network.

**Other sources:**
The problem has been also commented in:

- [Dota2 on GitHub](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Dota-2/issues/1070)
- [Bumblebee issue 626](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/626)

Comment: I have done your suggestion but it did'nt help